# How to trace a certain object in VC++ 6

Tags: c++, visual-c++, object, trace

i was wondering how to trace a certain object in VC++6.
It can be done by tracing the unique object ID with "Trace Points",
in more recent versions of visual studio. I still haven't figured
out how to do this in VC++ 6. Maybe you guys can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

zhengtonic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click on object, go to break point and select trace point :)

Answer (score 0):

In my spare time I continue work on my logging-package which will work with VC6. I switched it over to ETW several months back so the overhead is in the ballpark of 0.8-microsecond per trace statement.
This is of no use to you in the near term, but don't lose hope entirely.